# Std or boost atomic unsigned char[32]

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, char, atomic

I am trying to set a `unsigned char[32]` via a `cin` loop in `main` and make it accessible to all threads.  The method and delivery is less important than the ability to make this data available to all threads of an unknown number at compile time, `cores - 1`, whenever the data is reset.

The only ways I can envision this delivery with methods that work as expected are to either

1. Pass the data to the thread that sends work to the `cores - 1` threads from the network then send it from there to those threads.  This limits the performance of the worker threads because they are now dependent upon the managing thread because not all work comes from the managing thread, yet the worker threads are dependent upon the up to date `unsigned char[32[]`
2. Have each worker thread check for a change in the `unsigned char[32]` on each cycle.  The performance for this is horrible because of lock contention.

I don't believe that I'm able to use an `unsigned char[32]` with `std::atomic`; however, if that belief is incorrect, please show me how.

Therefore, I'm investigating if it's possible with `boost::atomic`, yet I'm having trouble understanding the [limitations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/atomic/limitations.html):

> Using non-POD-classes as template parameter to atomic results in undefined behavior: This means that any class containing a constructor, destructor, virtual methods or access control specifications is not a valid argument in C++98. C++11 relaxes this slightly by allowing "trivial" classes containing only empty constructors. Advise: Use only POD types.

I've found this on [POD](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/working-groups/fpcltf/Pkg/ISOcxx/doc/POD.html), but I'm still unsure if a `unsigned char[32]` can be used with `boost::atomic` safely according to my intent:

> The term POD is an acronym.  It stands for "plain old data" [p. 5, footnote 4], and is intended to suggest areas of substantive compatibility between comparable data types in C and C++.  The terms POD and POD object are often used interchangeably to refer to an object of POD type.
>
> The term POD types collectively refers to the following categories of C++ types, and encompasses both cv-qualified versions of these as well as arrays of these [§3.9, ¶10; §9, ¶4]:
>
> - scalar types, and
> - POD class types.

Many definitions follow, but I'm still unsure.

Can a `unsigned char[32]` be used with `std::atomic` or `boost::atomic`?  If so, how?  If not, how can my intent be implemented?

Comment: By "trying to use char[32] as an atomic", do you mean that the whole 32 bytes should be one atomic object, or that each of the 32 bytes should be individiually atomic? The former is DEFINITELY not possible. The latter may be possible to achieve in some way (at least there are instructions to do that [on machines that have atomic instructions at all, of course]!)

Comment: @Gracchus Isn't a simple `std::mutex` protecting the data sufficient here ?

Comment: Do you actually need it to be one and the same 32-byte data item, or can you copy it? If you can't copy, then I guess the solution is (fast)mutex or similar. (A fast mutex would only be one atomic instruction in the uncontented case - and if you have contention on the lock, you have some other problems...)

Comment: What is wrong with `std::atomic<unsigned char [32]>`?

Comment: So are you trying to give 32 bytes of the same data to each thread, or the same 32 bytes to each thread? It would help a lot if you describe what it is you are trying to do, rather than "what you think the solution is (in this case, atomics which doesn't work)" (The asking for the solution as you think it should be soolved is called XY problem or XY question)

Comment: @nwp Thank you for looking nwp!  I don't think they're accepted http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic as I am getting `/usr/include/c++/4.8/atomic: In instantiation of ‘struct std::atomic<unsigned char [32]>’: /usr/include/c++/4.8/atomic:175:7: error: function returning an array`

Comment: So, let me explore a bit more what you want to do: You have one set of 32 bytes that you want a number of different threads to detect if those 32 bytes have changed? Is that correct?

Comment: @Gracchus Sorry, didnt really pay attention. `std::atomic<std::array<unsigned char, 32>>` may work for you.

Comment: Reading THE SAME 32 bytes on multiple processor(cores) in different threads seems like a bad idea in the first place - what is it you are really wanting to do?

Comment: So, can you please describ (in your original question) what the flow of data is, and what you want to achieve? What is it that "changes" in the data - is it a new set of 32 bytes you want to give to the thread, or changes to the existing 32 bytes?

Comment: @Gracchus It should since `std::array` is a "trivial class" and I heard Herb Sutter say that atomic supports arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::atomic<std::array<unsigned char, 32>>` instead.